# Debugging with console.log. Is there shorthand to output a variable and its value?

Tags: javascript, debugging

When I use `console.log` to debug I typically use a line of code that looks like this.

`console.log("totalLength " +totalLength);`

My output includes the variable name and its value.

But is there shorthand for this?  Or is there maybe a better/faster/more convenient line of code to monitor variables?  Thanks so much!

Comment: The nearest I can think of is put all the variable to be debugged in an object, code might looks better however it doesn't make it shorter than this

Comment: You can use `%s` to create a format string and supply variable values as arguments. E.G. `console.log("The total length is %s", totalLength)`.  Works well with multiple variables as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's called *using the debugger*. Printing out variable values is not a good debugging practice.

If you are using Chrome, open up the Developer Tools and go to the Source tab. In the sidebar take a look at "Watch" and add your expressions in it.

[image]

You can also just look at source code panel. It will show all the variables' value by default. The "Watch" section allows more flexible expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor all the variables present in the global scope.

```
for(var b in window) { 
  if(window.hasOwnProperty(b)) console.log(b); 
}
```

The `window` object contains the information about the functions and vars present. You can essentially type `window` in console and monitor.